# Can a probability measure be concentrated on a lower-dimensional space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a linear subspace such that $\dim V = r < d$.

**Then can $\mu(V) \approx 1 = \mu(\mathbb{R}^d)$?**

I believe it can't be true. 
For example, let $\mu$ be the weighted Lebesgue measure (Gaussian distribution) in $\mathbb{R}^2$
where 
$$d\mu(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dxdy.$$ 
Then the measure of x-axis $V = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is
$$ \mu(V) = 0, \qquad \text{and} \qquad \dim V = 1.$$

In general, let $V$ be a $r$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Then by applying appropriate rotations, we may assume $x_1,\cdots,x_r$ axis generates $V$.
Thus $\mu(V) = 0$ as $x_n$ axis integration is 0.

Am I missing something? Or my derivation is good enough to justify 
$\mu(V) = 0$?

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible.  For instance, if you fix any point $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$, then you could define a probability measure $\mu$ by $\mu(A)=1$ if $a\in A$ and $\mu(A)=0$ if $a\not\in A$.  This is a perfectly good probability measure.  More generally, given your favorite probability measure $\nu$ on some subspace $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, you can get a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by defining $\mu(A)=\nu(A\cap V$).

Your error seems to be assuming the measure must be given by integrating some distribution function with respect to Lebesgue measure.  This is certainly not true of arbitrary measures; measures of this form are called *absolutely continuous* with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)